# What is the point of the Java keystores (JKS, JCEKS) when the keystore password is just as vulnerable as the keys themselves?

Tags: java, keystore

I have some code that encrypts some user data. Currently I have the key stored in a configuration file that gets loaded at runtime. This sucks for a number of reasons, namely that if someone gets access to the config file they have access to the secret key. So I started looking into the Java keystores, but I can't seem to justify them. The keystores require a password, which would be just as vulnerable as hardcoding the key. Am I missing something, or do key stores suffer the same weaknesses as hard coding the secret keys?

Comment: It's not really a weakness. If you want to decrypt something, you need a key. You can't decrypt something without having access to the key.

Comment: If you have your own server you can purchase some inexpensive hardware keystores, even some that do the encrtyption/decryption without reviling the keys, kind-of a mini-HSM. But is the server has the ability to decrypt the data there will be a potential vulnerability. Even the best encryption will be of no use if the data can be decrypted to display on a web page and that access has poor security.

Answer (score 1):

A common architecture I see is the application encrypts the data using a private key, or the application must decrypt database credentials for a specific dev/test/prod environment.  Developers commit code and configuration to a code repository.  However, the key used to encrypt/decrypt is created by another team and stored somewhere else. When the server or container is deployed, the keystore is deployed with it.  The codebase including the configuration files is built and deployed onto the the server.  The developer never have access to the decryption keys, the keys are never in the code repo.

Answer (score 0):

By using the JKS or any keystore really you are taking the first step toward offloading the key protection requirements from your application or server to the keystore or the user of that keystore.  There are plenty of guidelines for protecting keys and keystores that can get quite fancy (HSM's, etc..), but leveraging the JCE architecture is just first step. In the meantime might as well start baking security into your application.

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/11517/storage-of-secrets-keystores-hsms-and-the-rest

Answer (score 0):

In the keystore with an abstract application key you have access to several physical resource keys.

Indeed this is keystore access is a critical break point.
However the stored keys are centrally and again password protected stored.
Also updates of the stored keys are centrally done, instead of at a some point in the application.

Also updating the keystore's password is easier than updating stored passwords, which depend on usage, like other backend systems.